# How to implement a custom master page across all sites and sub sites

Tags: custom-masterpage

I've developed a new masterpage and I'm wanting to implement it accross all sites and subs sites. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a feature that deploys your master to the masterpage gallery and then set each webs masterpageurl to your master in the webs masterpage gallery.